# How to create pairs form python dictionary keys

Tags: python, algorithm, list, dictionary

For example I have a dictionary dict

```
my_dictionary= {'a': 20, 'c': 60, 'b': 10}
```

In this case I have 3 keys from the dictionary. I would like to make pairs and store them as tuples in a list. For the above case I would have this

```
[(a,b),(a,c),(b,c)]
```

Note: no repetition.

What would be the best way to go about it without any using any external modules.

Thank you for contribution.

Comment: Have you tried doing it with two loops?

Comment: don't call your dictionary, `dict`, since it is a builtin name

Comment: and why downvote?Please someone let me know so that I avoid this mistakes in future. i.e Downvote and comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> dd = {'a': 20, 'c': 60, 'b': 10}
>>> keys = [i for i in dd]
>>> [(keys[i],keys[j]) for i in range(len(keys)) for j in range(i+1,len(keys))]
[('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'b')]
>>>
```

and usually it's not a very good idea to call your variables using reserved words (like `dict`)

Comment: `[i for i in dd]` is simply `list(dd)`.  And you can avoid the `i != j` check by using `i+1` instead.

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> d = {'a': 20, 'c': 60, 'b': 10}
>>> list(combinations(d, r=2))
[('a', 'c'), ('a', 'b'), ('c', 'b')]
```

Comment: How can I go about it without using the itertools library

Comment: Yeah I agree with you this is the best way to go.I didn't know its part of the standard library. @lenik its true its homework, I am going to use it in production for it is neat and simple.@lenik example fits my requirement for now.Thanks alot